# Error : double nested forms in active admin with habtm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin

> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `events' for #
>   Did you mean?  eventusers):
>
> 1: insert_tag renderer_for(:new)
>
> app/admin/programs.rb:23:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
>   app/admin/programs.rb:22:in`block (4 levels) in '
>   app/admin/programs.rb:21:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
>   app/admin/programs.rb:17:in`block (2 levels) in '
>
> Doubled nested forms Programs -> events -> eventusers
>   joint tables : events_programs and events_eventusers

models:

```
class Program < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :events, join_table: 'events_programs'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :events, allow_destroy: true
end

class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :programs
  has_and_belongs_to_many :eventusers, join_table: 'events_eventusers'
       accepts_nested_attributes_for :eventusers, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Eventuser < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :events
end
```

admin/programs.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register Program do


permit_params :name, events_attributes: [:id, :name, :_destroy, eventuser_ids: []]#s_attributes: [:id, :name, :role, :_destroy]]


form do |f|
    f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys
    f.inputs do
        f.input :name


        f.inputs do
            f.has_many :events, allow_destroy: true do |a|
                a.input :events, as: :select, collection: Event.all.uniq.map{|e| e.name} #, :input_html => { :class => 'chosen-select' }
                a.inputs "users" do
                    a.has_many :eventusers do |a|
                        a.input :eventuser_ids, :as => :select, collection: Eventuser.all#.uniq.map{|e| [e.name, e.role]} , :input_html => { :class => 'chosen-select' }
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
    f.actions
end


end
```

Comment: What is your actual question? It's very unclear what you're asking.

Comment: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `events' for # Did you mean? eventusers):

1: insert_tag renderer_for(:new)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50810417/err-double-nested-form-with-habtm-in-active-admin ?